# Generalised KroneckerProduct that works like Outer[]

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Is there a Mathematica function that works like this:

`Function[f, A, B]`

where `f` is a function with two arguments, and `A` and `B` are matrices of equal dimension. The output would be another matrix of the same dimension with the elements `f[a11, b11], f[a12, b12], ...` etc. Basically the combinations from `KroneckerProduct` except with the generalised function feature of `Outer`.

Comment: `MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{u, v}, {s, t}}}, 2]` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what to make of your KroneckerProduct comment, but I think what you're looking for is MapThread:

```
MapThread[f, {matA, matB}, 2]
```